# How to increase parameter set limit in TFS?

Tags: parameter-sets

We have about 200 parameter sets, if i add another parameter set the last parameter set will disapear from the "All parameter sets" list.
How can we increase the max parameter set limit in TFS 2018?

Im referring to the parameter sets you create in TFS under Test > Parameters.

//Kind regards NB

Comment: You need more information

Comment: What information? @reckface

Comment: Are you referring to `Variable Groups`, variables in release definitions, parameters of a function?

Comment: Im referring to the parameter sets you create in TFS under Test > Parameters.
It seems like 200 parameter sets is visible default, but if you create a 201th parameter set you will still only see 200 parameter sets in the list.